# Addition some values in a table of mysql using php

Tags: mysql

i want to addition id's values. For Example

```
ID    Values
----------
b1     100
c2     100
c3     100
b1     50
```

now i want to addition id 1 values like this

```
ID    Values
----------
b1     150
c2     100
c3     100
```

which sql query should be written for this

Comment: What you're asking for is too broad and unclear. It would be **beneficial for you** to go over the help area if you haven't already https://stackoverflow.com/help and the related links inside it. Please read through that and you'll see how Stack Overflow works, *"learning the ropes"* as it were. It will give you a good idea on how to formulate a good question, to see what can and should not be asked, as well as what is expected from you. This was made and put into place in order to help you have a better and positive experience here, which is what everybody wants and aims for.

Comment: This does not happen from a single statement. You need to write a process

Comment: so what is the process for this?

Comment: @AtifRaja check the posted answer by Raymond. It should work for you. Please google `GROUP BY` and aggregation functions. You can study some tutorials on it; or refer the official documentation here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Query**

```
SELECT 
   Table1.ID
 , SUM(Table1.Values) AS `values`
FROM 
 Table1
GROUP BY 
 Table1.ID
order BY 
 Table1.ID
```

**Results**

```
| ID  | values |
| --- | ------ |
| b1  | 150    |
| c2  | 100    |
| c3  | 100    |
```

[demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8n4jzH2Ni5m9Sb8eDzgBqX/1)

Comment: Thanks !  and now if i want to take Total of whole values ..so whats steps i should be done?

Comment: " and now if i want to take Total of whole values ..so whats steps i should be done?" Not sure what you mean with total of whole values @AtifRaja but this query displays a total per ID group..

Comment: @AtifRaja you can take this whole query as a Derived table and run `SUM()` on it.